# How do I deselect a quad in the UV editor?

Tags: texturing, uv, topology

I'm trying to unwrap this mesh, and there's too many active quads throughout the islands. I can't deselect them, and there's multiple, so whenever I try and fix one piece, the others get screwed up.

Comment: deselect should be Ctrl LMB, lasso deselect should be Ctrl Shift RMB, does it work?

Comment: Maybe include a screen-grab of your UV window, including the parts of the header that show selection modes.. anything else you think might help us.

Comment: Even if you use the menu "Select >> None"?

Comment: Hi, Nathan .. welcome .. Please clarify this question by adding screenshots, or sharing a representative file on https://blend-exchange.com/